# Nonexistence of independent axiomatization of a theory in a finite language.

Tags: first-order-logic

This is a follow up to two previous questions. I mistakenly thought that the theory  of infinite sets in the language of equality had no axiomatization that was non-redundant. Now I am led to whether there is a theory in a finite language (necessarily non-finitely axiomatizable) that has no non-redundant axiomatization. Is there?

Comment: See my edit - I found a paper which reminded me of this question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can't happen in **any** language whatsoever. This was proved by Tarski for countable languages, and by Reznikoff for uncountable languages (see the end of this answer). See also Wojtylak's survey paper [*Independent axiomatizability of sets of sentences*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168007289900341).

---

For **countable** languages, there is a simple argument. Suppose I have a non-finitely-axiomatizable theory $T$ in a countable language. Since our language is countable we can enumerate $T$: $$T=\{\varphi_i: i\in \mathbb{N}\}.$$

First, we'll thin out $T$: let $$T'=\{\varphi_i: \bigwedge_{j<i}\varphi_j\not\vdash\varphi_i\}$$ be the set of "not-immediately-redundant" sentences in $T$. We trivially have that $T'$ is an axiomatization of $T$. This is *not* necessarily a redundant axiomatization, since we could have e.g. $\varphi_{17},\varphi_{42}\in T'$ with $\varphi_{42}\vdash\varphi_{17}$ still.

Enumerate $T'$ as $$T'=\{\psi_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$ We'll now "dominoize" everything: let $$\theta_i=(\bigwedge_{j<i}\psi_j)\implies\psi_i,$$ with the convention that $\theta_0=\psi_0$ *(the empty hypothesis is vacuously true)*.

It's easy to see that $$T^*:=\{\theta_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ axiomatizes $T$, the key point being that $\bigwedge_{j\le i}\theta_j\vdash\psi_i$. I claim that $T^*$ is in addition irredundant.

To see this, fix $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and consider the sentence $$\eta_i=(\bigwedge_{j<i}\psi_j)\wedge\neg\psi_i.$$ We have $\eta_i\vdash\theta_k$ for all $k\not=i$: for $k<i$ this is built directly into $\eta_i$, and for $k>i$ this is because the hypothesis of the conditional becomes vacuous. But also clearly $\eta_i\vdash\neg\theta_i$. And finally, by definition of $T'$ we know that $\eta_i$ is consistent and hence $\eta_i\not\vdash\theta_i$. Putting this all together we get $$\{\theta_k: k\not=i\}\not\vdash\theta_i$$ as desired.

---

What about **uncountable** languages? The above argument breaks down almost immediately when we try to generalize it in this way.

It turns out that this broader question was answered by Reznikoff in 1965: every first-order theory has a non-redundant axiomatization. Reznikoff's paper is in French, and [an English version of the argument](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5171.pdf) was presented by Souldatos a while ago. An interesting feature of the argument is the role of Craig's interpolation theorem. The non-triviality of this result leads naturally to further questions about irredundancy in other logics, and I think a lot is open here. The only papers I know of are [Hjorth/Souldatos](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.3422.pdf) building off of [X. Caicedo](https://math.uniandes.edu.co/archivos/publicaciones/IndependentsetsofaxiomsinL-kappa,alpha.pdf) giving some positive results for $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$, and Wojtylak's survey mentioned at the top of this answer (note that Wojtylak postdates all the others except Hjorth/Souldatos, which doesn't refer to it), but that's it as far as I'm aware.