# Does every equational theory have an independent equational axiomatization?

Tags: universal-algebra

An equational theory is a theory axiomatized by a set of equations. Does every such theory have an independent equational axiomatization? Independent means no axiom in the set can be deleted without loss of theorems.

Comment: Two quick comments. First, note that the "obvious" argument of enumerating the original theory and recursively selecting "not-yet-provable" axioms does not work since later axioms may prove earlier axioms, and throwing out old axioms may result in the "limit axiomatization" being too weak. Second, note that [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3289290/28111) is a red herring: even if the original axiomatization is equational, the new axioms will not be equations but rather **implications** whose conclusion is an equation and whose hypothesis is a conjunction of equations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Finite algebras with no independent basis of identities,
I. M. ISAEV,
Algebra univers. 37 (1997) 440-444

describes a finite algebra whose equational theory has no independent equational axiomatization. The algebra is a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field equipped with a certain nonassociative bilinear multiplication.