# Generalization of a previous model theory question regarding independent sets of sentences.

Tags: logic, model-theory

This is a follow up to and a generalization of my previous model theory question, here: [Can an independent subset of a theory be completed to axiomatize the theory while preserving independence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699853/can-an-independent-subset-of-a-theory-be-completed-to-axiomatize-the-theory-whil). Let $L$ be a first-order theory. Let $S$ be a consistent set of sentences, this time not necessarily deductively closed, unlike in the previous question. Let $I$ be an independent subset of $S$. (As before, independence means no redundant sentences). Does there exist a set $I'$ such that $I \subseteq I' \subseteq S$, $I'$ is independent, and the deductive closure of $I'$ is the same as the deductive closure of $S$? This time, I am inclined to think the answer is no. There should be a counterexample for some language $L$ and some small finite set $S$ and subset $I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that there is a counterexample to your claim.  I don't have a finite set $S$, but here is a not-too-complicated infinite one.

Take $L = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots\}$ where the $a_i$'s are distinct constant symbols.  For each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\sigma_i$ be the sentence expressing that $a_1, \ldots, a_i$ are all distinct.  Let $S = \{\sigma_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Observe that the only independent subsets of $S$ are $\emptyset$ and singletons (i.e., sets of the form $\{\sigma_i\}$ for some $i$).  This is because if $i < j$ then $\sigma_j$ implies $\sigma_i$.  On the other hand, $\{\sigma_i\}$ does not have the same deductive closure as $S$, because $S \vdash a_1 \neq a_{i+1}$ while $\{\sigma_i\} \not\vdash a_1 \neq a_{i+1}$.

This shows that no subset of $S$ is both independent and has the same deductive closure as $S$; in particular, $S$ is a counterexample to your statement no matter what $I$ you choose.

Comment: I just thought of a counterexample involving a 3-element set $S$. Granted, it is a propositional logic example rather than a first-order logic example, but it can be easily adapted to first-order logic. Just let $S$ be the set $\{P,Q,P \land Q \land R \}$, and let $I$ be $\{P,Q\}$. Then it is easily verified that this is a counterexample to the claim.